# I downloaded Java and DocFetcher, but they try to open in Calibre

Tags: macos, java, dmg

I downloaded Java and DocFetcher online, but they downloaded as dmg files and when I try to open them, they try to open in Calibre, an e-book software program.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Get info, and change the opening App there.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. How do I get the info (what info?) and how do I change the opening App?

Comment: Nevermind I found these instructions: https://www.isumsoft.com/computer/3-ways-to-mount-dmg-files-on-macos.html